# Sending dynamic variables to ftl format

Tags: java, html, dynamic

I'm building a ftl template and i have to send several variables to the page:

```
emailParams.put("anagCode_"+count, anag.getCode());
emailParams.put("name"+count, anag.getName());
emailParams.put("surname"+count, anag.getSurname());
```

Then i send the total number of those anags:

```
emailParams.put("count", countEmail);
```

Now, how can i recover every single value? I don't know how concat the Strings on ftl page:

```
<#list 0..count as i>
${anagCode_i}
</#list>
```

This doesen't work. I tried even with `{anagCode_+i}` or `{anagCode_}i` and others.

Can someone help me with this?

ps: i CAN'T use the DTOs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
${.vars["anagCode" + i]!}
```

This will access the variable-map in the FTL and fetch the variable with the name "anagCode"+i, which is what you would like to see.

Comment: Meh. It doesen't works. It say that the variables is null or missing.

Comment: try to use the variable name directly ($(anagCode_1)) to check and debug if your code works.

Comment: You tried ${.vars["anagCode_" + i]}, right? I adopted the answer, this should work now.